# "Close" button won't work in announcement message boxes

Tags: 2010, list

We finally went into a pilot stage with our first page on our new intranet. We have noticed a small quirk, though; the close button will not do anything in the message box prompted through clicking an entry in an announcement list. The X in the upper right corner will close it, but clicking on the close button results in an "error on page" in the lower left pane of the web browser. We JUST rolled it out, so we'd like to get it resolved before too many people notice. Any thoughts??

Comment: What browser are you testing with?  It works fine for me in Chrome 13 and IE 8.

Comment: We are using IE 8. We're well aware that it really isn't built for IE 6 and lower, and have listed that caveat on the page where it is listed.

Comment: Find out what javascript is causing the error.  You can go into IE and under the Internet Options->Advanced, in the Browsing section, check "Display a notification about every script error."  This should help you determine what javascript is causing the error.  Also, what IE zone is the SharePoint site running in?  If it is internet, try putting it in Intranet to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: We have it in the intranet. The problem is that we have it on a test server (since our Enterprise license still isn't valid yet), and we have created a DNS for it and are mirroring it to the current intranet (we're replacing the current intranet with the Sharepoint one very soon, and this is our first pilot); it's having a hard time referencing a URI on the test Sharepoint server. Thanks for the response. Put it in question form and I'll select it as my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having DNS issues, it could just be something as simple as setting up an Alternate Access Mapping on the new site, so it accepts the DNS entry that you have pointing at it.